# Prestashop FatalErrorException in Admin panel after move to other server

Tags: php, html, symfony, composer-php, prestashop

I installed Prestashop at one server, then move my shop to second hosting.
Database was moved and connected and front office is working but backoffice is not. When I log in to the Admin panel, left side text is missing and most of menu throw an exception:

```
         (1/1) FatalErrorException

         Compile Error: PHP Startup: Failed opening required '/autoinstalator/prestashop1/vendor/composer/../symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Asset/Context/RequestStackContext.php' 
         (include_path='/autoinstalator/prestashop1/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/autoinstalator/prestashop1/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/autoinstalator/prestashop1/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/autoinstalator/prestashop1/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/:/usr/local/php73/lib/pear')

    in DebugClassLoader.php line 156
```

DebugClassLoader.php is not opening in browser ("Page is not found").

I cleared cache in app/cache and var/cache.
I have some knowledge in c## and php, but Im little confused about "symfony" and "composer". I assume I need to rebuild that composer, but don't know how.

Do I need a SSH connection and console to execute this commands below?

```
composer clear-cache
composer dump-autoload
```

Please can someone advice me what I should do to fix that that?
Greetings

Comment: if the files exist, they probably have the wrong permissions (not readable by php script), if they don't exist, you have to `composer install`. This can either be done on the server via ssh or locally and then uploaded (pay attention to php version though)

Comment: They are existing. Permissions are 644 for files and 755 for directories.
Both server php versions is 7.2. How can I do this thru ssh? Can you explain? Thanks